# Biggest index with a value in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I have severals arrays, and I would like to find the biggest index value.

```
var test1 = [0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0];
var test2 = [0, 400, 200, 0, 250, 0];
var test3 = [240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var test4 = [240, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0];
```

Below are my differents arrays, and for each one, I would like to retrieve something like this

```
test1 : 2, 200
test2 : 4, 250
test3 : 0, 240
test4 : 4, 100
```

I tried something like this but it break when I get a value different of zero, and not the one with the biggest index value.

```
function seekAndFind(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {        
        if ( array[i] !== 0 ) {
            console.log(array[i]);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JeremDsgn/P4xLd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just go backwards through the array?

```
function seekAndFind(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {        
        if ( array[i] !== 0 ) {
            console.log(i, array[i]);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong indexing in the loop, use `for (var i = array.length - 1; i--; )`.

Comment: I didn't thinking of this approach, but it works perfectly, just fix the loop condition `for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`. Thanks.